# Recent Garbage collection survey paper

Tags: reference-request, memory-management, garbage-collection

Many years ago I read a GC survey paper that was updated every few years with advances; I tried to find such a paper today to point a questioner on Stackoverflow at.

However all I can find is very old survey papers that don’t include current thinking on items like hardware assistance.

Comment: Have you tried searching at Google Scholar?  Have you tried using Google Scholar to see what newer papers cite those older survey papers, and see if you can spot your paper among them?  Those are standard literature search techniques.

Comment: Do you have titles, names, or dates for your survey papers? Where was it disseminated?

Comment: @babou, It was from the days when FTP and new groups where more common then web sites.   I don't have a copy of the paper, so don't know the names etc.

Comment: At that time, the main GC survey was the one written by Cohen in computing surveys. There was a more recent and more complete one later (late 90ies or early 2000, but I do not have the name in mind). I must have a copy somewhere ... I'll check. Then ther is a book on GC (well, at least one). But even a book does not cover it all :-)

Answer (score 1):

the area seems to be "mature" in the sense that garbage collection theory/ dynamics is relatively well understood, surveys that come up in searches are years old and many state-of-the-art algorithms are now implemented, and maybe research in the area is far less common or active. also hardware assisted garbage collection seems an uncommon combination theoretically (also/ incl operating system aware/ crosscutting such as algorithms that intentionally mesh well by design with caches, paging, virtualization, etc). speaking as a practitioner in the field, garbage collection algorithms tuned with hardware features or OS mechanisms seems a promising idea that hasnt been explored much.

here is one survey turned up of 3 state of the art algorithms from 2013 and there is a hardware mechanism on the 1<sup>st</sup> (for reference counting).

- [Low Pause-Time Garbage Collection
  Written Preliminary Examination II](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~delozier/docs/wpe.pdf) / DeLozier